# How can be proven that any number X is greater,lesser or equal to any other number Y?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, integers

I have looked for it on the internet, really, but all I have found are particular cases like 1 > 0, or such. Is there an algebraic proof for proving that x > y or, x = y, or x < y? I thought of using Euclid's Fundamental theorem of Arithmetic as a tool, and comparing the primes that produce a compound number, but I still would have to prove that those primes (and primes in general) are ones greater (or lesser) than others.

Comment: if you are given two numbers $x,y$, exactly one of 3 things is possible: $x<y. x = y, $ or $ x >y$. Why would you think $x>y$ is the only thing?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? What do you mean any number $X$ is greate rthan any other number $Y$?

Comment: I already rephrased it. What I'm trying to say is, that I have two numbers, let's say they are 52 and 48, obviously 52 > 48(and that implies 48 < 52), but how can I prove this obvious statement? and how can I prove it for any pair of numbers X and Y.

Comment: Are you asking about the underlying axioms that govern $<, =, >$? Of course, if you have arbitrary $x$ and $y$, you can't really say anything about their ordering

Comment: Google ordered field axioms. If x < y then x+z < y+z.  If a >0 and x <y then a*x < a*y.  And so on.  From these we can prove $x^2 > 0$ and therefore 1>0.  From there ... well it all falls in place 58 > 42 because 16 > 0 because 16 = 4^2. and so on.

Comment: Oh, ok, I was asking about that, I didn't know the name of such axioms.
Thank you really much.

Comment: I foudn this useful document on such axioms.

http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~kauffman/axioms1.pdf

Comment: Imo, this question is nonsense. This is like trying to prove a definition. However, I think it may happen to those who do not know what mathematics, making this kind of misthinking. I guess, you are thinking that such ordering exists there in nature, so you are trying to prove that using mathematical language, but mathematics is not like that.. We model and construct number systems and **define** orderings.

Comment: Rubertos, I think we can be a little more generous than that.  That 52 > 48 isn't arbitrary.  It's true because 52=48 + 4 and 4 > 0.  And 4 > 0 is due to axioms.  And asking what *are* the axioms is not only valid; it's really essential for anyone with curiosity.  The thing about these things is it isn't the proof that is important.  It's how to precisely define what we mean.

Comment: I know this question is kinda silly, it only arises due to a more, lets say "philosophical" question I have. Firstly I thought about the  set of natural numbers, obviously it goes from 1 to infinite, right?, then we have Intgers, and the go from -infinite to +infinite right? so, thaat means that in this two sets, if we have any x number, we could go x+1, or x-1 infinitely. But if when we have the set of rationals, it seems that this is no longer true, since, what is the next number to x? well, x.0000000... and it goes infinitely.... (next comment)

Comment: one would expect that number to hit one at some point, like x.00000...001, but it obviously never does, and if it did, it wouldn't hit 1, but any of the numbers that are lesser that it, but this number is infinite, since it would be 0.0000000... and it never ends? so does this mean that in the set of rational numbers, and from there on, numbers don't have a next number? and any number greater than x, is just an infinite number? this question stems from this doubt. I'm not a professional mathematicians, so I could be saying nonsense.

Comment: Key to your example is 0 < x < y iff 0 < 1/y < 1/x. So as we always have n < n + 1 < ..... we always have 0 < .... 1/(n+1) < 1/n... etc.  And yes, it does mean the rationals are "dense" in the way you describe.  Thus was a *good* question in my opininion.

Answer (score 1):

Different text may do these differently but they are all equivalent.

x < y;x=y; or y < x are mutually exclusive and exhaustive by definition.

Addition and multiplication (and the inverses subtraction and division) are given by fiat so that a+0=a 1xa =a, a+(-a)=0.  If a ne 0 then ax1/a =1 and a (b+c)=ab+bc.  These are axioms.

From these we can prove basic this like (-(-a))=a and (-a)(-b)=ab and 0xa=0 and so on.

We are then given two *essential* axioms of order.

x+y < x+z if y < z

And xy > 0 if x >0 and y > 0.

From there we can prove everything.

We can prove if x > 0 then - x < 0

If x >0 and y < z then xy < xz.

That $x^2 > 0$ is $x \ne 0$ and in particular $1^2 = 1 > 0$.

That if 0 < x < y then 0 < 1/y < 1/x

So that's how we can compare any two rational numbers.

But what of irrational.  Well when we define the reals it is as the limits of sequences of rationals and the laws of order are extended.

Answer (score 0):

You have to start somewhere. Say we have the integers and we know how to add, subtract, and multiply. This distinguishes the multiplicative identity element $1$. We say that $1$ is "positive," and recursively define positive numbers by declaring that if $p$ is positive, then so is $p+1$. This gives us the usual set of positive numbers.

Define $a<b$ if $b-a$ is positive. Then if $a\neq b$, then either $a-b$ is positive or $-(a-b)=b-a$ is positive, so either $a<b$ or $b<a$, which is what we wanted to show.

What about $52$ and $48$? Well, $52-48=4\ldots$

Comment: Axioms can go deeper than that.  We can prove for instance that 1 > 0.  Of course we do have to be given axioms.  a > 0 and x <y then ax < ay is one, from which (and others) we can prove 1 >0.  On the other hand if we had that as an axiom maybe we could prove x < y then ax < ay.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you're asking how to prove that $\le$ is a total ordering. The answer depends on the definition of $\le$. If I define $x\prec y$ iff $x$ perfectly divides $y$ then $2 \prec 4$ but $3\not\prec 4$ and $4\not\prec 3$ and $3\not= 4$.

Suppose I define '$x\le y$' based upon the sign of $(y-x)$.

$(y-x)$ zero or positive : $x\le y$

$(y-x)$ zero or negative : $y\le x$

Since the difference of two numbers must be at least one of these cases, the ordering has totality. To be a total order I'd also have to show

(antisymmetry) if $a\leq b$ and $b\leq a$ then $a=b$ and

(transitivity) if $a\leq b$ and $b\leq c$ then $a\leq c$